# Filtering dataframe in R based on the condition on last column without hard coding column name

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering, subset

Below is my dataframe.

```
name    m   d1  d2  d3  d4  d5
name1   m1  45  18  69  35  20
name2   m2  34  19  16  25  0
name3   m3  18  38  0   66  29
name4   m4  52  9   58  84  0
name5   m5  45  75  76  65  79
```

I would like to get results as shown below. Basically I want to check if the last column has any 0s, then filter only those rows. Please note, I don't want to rely on the column name directly using dollar($) symbol.

```
name    m   d1  d2  d3  d4  d5
name2   m2  34  19  16  25  0
name4   m4  52  9   58  84  0
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working. It selects all the rows which meets certain condition on the last column. I'm sure there must be better way than this, but after trying some options, this worked for me.

```
my.df[my.df[,ncol(my.df)] == 0,]
```

Comment: I doubt there is a better way, this seems pretty straight forward for R. It's also exactly what my answer was suggesting.

Comment: yes, I was aware of ncol thing, but couldn't actually get the correct results with all the rows, I was messing up somewhere with the squared brackets. thanks for your tip though.

Comment: I suggest adding some code to your question next time so it's more clear which area you are stuck on. It sounded to me like you knew how to filter but didn't know how to address the last column. I think your code above is the idiomatic way to do this in R.